# How Qt Runs On Android?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I want to learn how Qt runs on Android? I know `Qt` is native for mobile apps. Qt has got a lot of modules (e.g `Qt Sensors`, `Qt Bluetooth`, `Qt AndroidExtras`). Qt is native for mobile, but we can call `Android SDK Java codes` from Qt / C++. Well, how runs the Java codes from Qt for Android? Does works Java VM in Qt background? How runs Java codes in Qt? What is the logic for this job?
Qt is using  `QtAndroidExtras` calling Java codes for Android. But I want to use pure jni (with jni.h file) calling Java codes for Android. Because I want to use jni code both Qt and FireMonkey. So, I wonder how do Java codes run in Qt without `QtAndroidExtras`. My short question: I want to write a module like `QtAndroidExtras`, this module for Android. It is for calling Android SDK classes (or Java codes) from C++. How can I do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To run Java code in your Qt Android application you should use the [Qt Android Extras](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html) module which contains additional functionality for development on Android.

You can use JNI to call a Java function from Qt or callback a Qt function from Java.

```
bool retVal = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<jint>
                        ("com/MyApp/JavaClass" // class name
                        , "SomeMethod" // method name
                        , "(I)I" // signature
                        , val);
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew `Qt AndroidExtras` module already. But I wonder how can I call Java methods from Qt without `Qt AndroidExtras`? I think I need **jni.h** file. Do you know call Java methods from C++ with **jni.h**?